# problem understanding Python Sokoban code

Tags: python, algorithm

I am trying to build a Sokoban puzzle application in Python.

(description of the rules:
http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sokoban)

I successfully implemented the game, but I thought it would be better if the computer can calculate the best solution to solve a specific puzzle.

While I was looking for a reference, I came across this [Python implementation on Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sokoban#Python):

> ```
> from array import array
> from collections import deque
> import psyco
>      
> data = []
> nrows = 0
> px = py = 0
> sdata = ""
> ddata = ""
>
> def init(board):
>     global data, nrows, sdata, ddata, px, py
>     data = filter(None, board.splitlines())
>     nrows = max(len(r) for r in data)
>  
>     maps = {' ':' ', '.': '.', '@':' ', '#':'#', '$':' '}
>     mapd = {' ':' ', '.': ' ', '@':'@', '#':' ', '$':'*'}
>  
>     for r, row in enumerate(data):
>         for c, ch in enumerate(row):
>             sdata += maps[ch]
>             ddata += mapd[ch]
>             if ch == '@':
>                 px = c
>                 py = r
>  
> def push(x, y, dx, dy, data):
>     if sdata[(y+2*dy) * nrows + x+2*dx] == '#' or \
>        data[(y+2*dy) * nrows + x+2*dx] != ' ':
>         return None
>  
>     data2 = array("c", data)
>     data2[y * nrows + x] = ' '
>     data2[(y+dy) * nrows + x+dx] = '@'
>     data2[(y+2*dy) * nrows + x+2*dx] = '*'
>     return data2.tostring()
>  
> def is_solved(data):
>     for i in xrange(len(data)):
>         if (sdata[i] == '.') != (data[i] == '*'):
>             return False
>     return True
>  
> def solve():
>     open = deque([(ddata, "", px, py)])
>     visited = set([ddata])
>     dirs = ((0, -1, 'u', 'U'), ( 1, 0, 'r', 'R'),
>             (0,  1, 'd', 'D'), (-1, 0, 'l', 'L'))
>  
>     lnrows = nrows
>     while open:
>         cur, csol, x, y = open.popleft()
>  
>         for di in dirs:
>             temp = cur
>             dx, dy = di[0], di[1]
>  
>             if temp[(y+dy) * lnrows + x+dx] == '*':
>                 temp = push(x, y, dx, dy, temp)
>                 if temp and temp not in visited:
>                     if is_solved(temp):
>                         return csol + di[3]
>                     open.append((temp, csol + di[3], x+dx, y+dy))
>                     visited.add(temp)
>             else:
>                 if sdata[(y+dy) * lnrows + x+dx] == '#' or \
>                    temp[(y+dy) * lnrows + x+dx] != ' ':
>                     continue
>  
>                 data2 = array("c", temp)
>                 data2[y * lnrows + x] = ' '
>                 data2[(y+dy) * lnrows + x+dx] = '@'
>                 temp = data2.tostring()
>  
>                 if temp not in visited:
>                     if is_solved(temp):
>                         return csol + di[2]
>                     open.append((temp, csol + di[2], x+dx, y+dy))
>                     visited.add(temp)
>  
>     return "No solution"
>  
>  
> level = """\
> #######
> #     #
> #     #
> #. #  #
> #. $$ #
> #.$$  #
> #.#  @#
> #######"""
>  
> psyco.full()
> init(level)
> print level, "\n\n", solve()
> ```

It basically reads a text string representing the puzzle, and solves it using BFS.

One of the things that I had trouble understanding, however, was what `sdata` and `ddata` represent respectively. It looks like `sdata` and `ddata` map different characters, but I don't understand why.

Any ideas?

Thanks :)

Comment: Perhaps you might want to take a look at http://math-in-python.com/plhak/sokoban website. At the bottom of the page are links to source code for the sokoban game. It might serve you as reference code.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at what the data is mapping to:

```
. = end point
@ = the guy
# = wall
$ = diamond
maps = {' ':' ', '.': '.', '@':' ', '#':'#', '$':' '}
mapd = {' ':' ', '.': ' ', '@':'@', '#':' ', '$':'*'}
```

ssata appears to be a map of the end point and and the wall.

ddata appears to be a map of the player and the diamonds.

Answer (score 0):

**sdata** holds the *static* data from the maze (the parts that don't change as we search), and **ddata** holds the *dynamic* data (the parts that do change as we search), and is used to hold the initial state.

It is probably done this way because its possible for boxes and the guy to be in the same position as a goal, which would make much of the code more complex to implement.

It is the **ddata** that is initially pushed onto the open list as the start position for the search, and into the visited set to mark positions that have already been searched.